# Oracle: Pipe Query Results Without Knowing The Column Types

Tags: oracle, plsql

I know that this is possible:

```
SQL> create or replace type tp_asset as object (assetId number, asset_name varchar2(100), asset_val number)
  2  /
Type created
SQL> create or replace type tp_tab_asset is table of tp_asset;
  2  /
Type created
SQL> create or replace function fnc_AssetAttributeByType(p_num in number) return tp_tab_asset pipelined as
  2    v_tp_asset tp_asset;
  3  begin
  4    for i in 1 .. 3
  5      loop
  6      v_tp_asset := tp_asset(i, 'ABC', i * 3);
  7      pipe row (v_tp_asset);
  8    end loop;
  9    return;
 10  end;
 11  /
Function created
```

But this seems incredibly stupid. Why would I want to maintain a list of columns in two places? I'm translating T-SQL to Oracle and I'd like to do the following:

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION fnc_AssetAttributeByType(
    p_ATTRIBUTETYPEID IN NUMBER)
  RETURN ******TABLE???????? pipelined
AS
BEGIN
  FOR j IN
  (
    SELECT
      a.AssetID,
      ShortName,
      LongName,
      ATTRIBUTEVALUE
    FROM
      DBO$ASSET A
    INNER JOIN dbo$asset_attribute aa
    ON
      A.ASSETID = AA.ASSETID
    INNER JOIN dbo$attribute att
    ON
      AA.ATTRIBUTEID = ATT.ATTRIBUTEID
    WHERE
      ATTRIBUTETYPEID = p_ATTRIBUTETYPEID
  )
  LOOP
    pipe row (j);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
```

Tell me if I'm sane or if this is not the way of the Oracle super sayans

Comment: Your query almost certainly isn't doing what you want `ATTRIBUTETYPEID = ATTRIBUTETYPEID` will compare the column of that name to the column of that name.  The parameter `ATTRIBUTETYPEID` won't be used.  What are the two places the list of columns is maintained?  One is the object type, what is the other?  The different tables that data is being read from?  Unless you want the result to always match the definition of a single table, I'm not sure that I see the problem.  In this case, a view would certainly seem simpler than a table function.

Comment: True. But the question isn't architecture related. I'd like to do precisely what I asked was possible. You're correct about the location of the columns. It seems like every example of this I find would have me duplicate every column involved.

Comment: This function call is actually satisfying a `LEFT JOIN` like so: `LEFT JOIN  TABLE(fnc_AssetAttributeByType(1))`

Answer (score 0):

There's one alternative I could think of declaring a type inside a package, where you can do it by using the %rowtype columns of a view (borrowing from @Justin Cave).

```
SQL> col shortname format a20
SQL> col longname format a20
SQL> drop table dbo$asset;
Table dropped
SQL> drop table dbo$asset_attribute;
Table dropped
SQL> drop table dbo$attribute;
Table dropped
SQL> create table dbo$asset (assetid number);
Table created
SQL> create table dbo$asset_attribute (attributeid number, assetid number, shortname varchar2(100), longname varchar2(100));
Table created
SQL> create table dbo$attribute (attributeid number, assetid number, attributevalue number, attributetypeid number);
Table created
SQL> insert into dbo$asset values (1);
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into dbo$asset_attribute values (10, 1, 'ATT1', 'ATTRIBUTE1');
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into dbo$asset_attribute values (20, 1, 'ATT2', 'ATTRIBUTE2');
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into dbo$attribute values (10, 1, 999.99, 444);
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into dbo$asset values (2);
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into dbo$asset_attribute values (30, 2, 'ATT1', 'ATTRIBUTE1');
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into dbo$asset_attribute values (40, 2, 'ATT2', 'ATTRIBUTE2');
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into dbo$attribute values (40, 2, 888.99, 555);
1 row inserted
SQL> create or replace view vw_assetattributebytype as
  2  SELECT a.assetid, shortname, longname, attributevalue, attributetypeid
  3    FROM dbo$asset a
  4    JOIN dbo$asset_attribute aa ON a.assetid = aa.assetid
  5    JOIN dbo$attribute att ON aa.attributeid = att.attributeid;
View created
SQL> create or replace package pck_asset is
  2    type tp_assetattributebytype is table of vw_assetattributebytype%rowtype;
  3  
  4    function fnc_assetattributebytype(p_attributetypeid in number) return tp_assetattributebytype pipelined;
  5  end pck_asset;
  6  /
Package created
SQL> create or replace package body pck_asset is
  2  
  3    function fnc_assetattributebytype(p_attributetypeid in number) return tp_assetattributebytype pipelined is
  4    begin
  5      for j in (select *
  6                  from vw_assetattributebytype
  7                 where attributetypeid = p_attributetypeid)
  8      loop
  9        pipe row(j);
 10      end loop;
 11    end fnc_assetattributebytype;
 12  
 13  end pck_asset;
 14  /
Package body created
SQL> select *
  2    from table(pck_asset.fnc_assetattributebytype(444));
   ASSETID SHORTNAME            LONGNAME             ATTRIBUTEVALUE ATTRIBUTETYPEID
---------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------- ---------------
         1 ATT1                 ATTRIBUTE1                   999,99             444

SQL>
```

The thing is you need to add the filter column ATTRIBUTETYPEID to the view in my example. There are means of working around it and it's fairly simple even though uses an application context to filter inside the view. If you must keep your view with only the columns originally in the query you can do this instead and alas:

```
SQL> col shortname format a20
SQL> col longname format a20
SQL> drop table dbo$asset;
Table dropped
SQL> drop table dbo$asset_attribute;
Table dropped
SQL> drop table dbo$attribute;
Table dropped
SQL> create table dbo$asset (assetid number);
Table created
SQL> create table dbo$asset_attribute (attributeid number, assetid number, shortname varchar2(100), longname varchar2(100));
Table created
SQL> create table dbo$attribute (attributeid number, assetid number, attributevalue number, attributetypeid number);
Table created
SQL> insert into dbo$asset values (1);
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into dbo$asset_attribute values (10, 1, 'ATT1', 'ATTRIBUTE1');
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into dbo$asset_attribute values (20, 1, 'ATT2', 'ATTRIBUTE2');
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into dbo$attribute values (10, 1, 999.99, 444);
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into dbo$asset values (2);
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into dbo$asset_attribute values (30, 2, 'ATT1', 'ATTRIBUTE1');
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into dbo$asset_attribute values (40, 2, 'ATT2', 'ATTRIBUTE2');
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into dbo$attribute values (40, 2, 888.99, 555);
1 row inserted
SQL> create or replace context ctx_asset using pck_asset;
Context created
SQL> create or replace view vw_assetattributebytype as
  2  SELECT a.assetid, shortname, longname, attributevalue
  3    FROM dbo$asset a
  4    JOIN dbo$asset_attribute aa ON a.assetid = aa.assetid
  5    JOIN dbo$attribute att ON aa.attributeid = att.attributeid
  6   WHERE attributetypeid = sys_context('ctx_asset', 'attributetypeid');
View created
SQL> create or replace package pck_asset is
  2    type tp_assetattributebytype is table of vw_assetattributebytype%rowtype;
  3  
  4    function fnc_assetattributebytype(p_attributetypeid in number) return tp_assetattributebytype pipelined;
  5    procedure prc_set_attributetype(p_attributetypeid in number);
  6  
  7  end pck_asset;
  8  /
Package created
SQL> create or replace package body pck_asset is
  2  
  3    procedure prc_set_attributetype(p_attributetypeid in number) is
  4    begin
  5      dbms_session.set_context('ctx_asset', 'attributetypeid', p_attributetypeid);
  6    end;
  7  
  8    function fnc_assetattributebytype(p_attributetypeid in number) return tp_assetattributebytype pipelined is
  9    begin
 10      -- sets the filter on the application context for the view
 11      prc_set_attributetype(p_attributetypeid);
 12  
 13      for j in (select *
 14                  from vw_assetattributebytype)
 15      loop
 16        pipe row(j);
 17      end loop;
 18    end fnc_assetattributebytype;
 19  
 20  end pck_asset;
 21  /
Package body created
SQL> select *
  2    from table(pck_asset.fnc_assetattributebytype(555));
   ASSETID SHORTNAME            LONGNAME             ATTRIBUTEVALUE
---------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------
         2 ATT2                 ATTRIBUTE2                   888,99

SQL>
```

I made a lot of assumptions on your table structures and they may be incorrect, forgive me for any mistakes. The idea was to show a sample code running.

Comment: Great effort and I appreciate this, but I can not prepend a package name to all the existing calls to the TSQL function. I must use something like this `fnc_assetattributebytype(555)` instead of `pck_asset.fnc_assetattributebytype(555)`. So far I've had to compromise by `pipelining` and doing this: `TABLE(fnc_assetattributebytype(555)` in my join clauses. I'm not thrilled about it.

Comment: A typical way to circumvent this is to create a function "fnc_assetattributebytype" like you did and have this standalone function call the packaged.function (pck_asset.fnc_assetattributebytype), like a façade. It's also useful when for security concerns, because you can only grant execute to the whole package or not at all, this is also a way to offer only one function out of the package to another user.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create an Oracle function that returns results of unknown column types using ANYDATASET and Oracle Data Cartridge.

The only implementation I've seen of this is Adrian Billington's [Dictionary Long Application](https://github.com/oracle-developer/dla).  The program is meant for converting LONG columns into CLOBs to make querying the data dictionary easier.  By removing the LONG and CLOB code it would become a more generic dynamic query engine.

While that's a great program, I would generally recommend against using it.  There are many bugs and limitations.  The ANY* types are rarely used and full of surprises.

Unfortunately this is mostly a link-only answer.  Solving this seemingly simple task requires hundreds of lines of Byzantine code.  Which is another reason why I recommend you find another way to do this, even if it means creating extra TYPEs.

Comment: This looks amazing. Have you any experience? I'm wondering where - besides the github repo - I can find (a shorter) example. Maybe point out a few key lines in AB's source that I should change. Thanks though. I appreciate it.

Comment: Funny you should mention that; after I posted this I thought it would be nice to have a simpler example.  I'm working on one [here](https://github.com/jonheller1/method4), but it probably won't be finished for a few days.  The code is complex, and there's a thorough description [on oracle-developer.net](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=422).  But in my mind the most important part is the beginning of ODCITableDescribe and ODCITableStart.  One of the changes I made was to intercept the "stmt" with a function, `change_statement`, and that's where the magic will go.

Comment: I've used code like this a few times to solve some oddly dynamic situations - for example an application where the number of schemas was not known at run time.  It's the ultimate in dynamic SQL but there's a big price to pay in code complexity.  Writing SQL to generate SQL is tough, and you'll run into some strange bugs and ORA-600 errors when you use the wrong combination of advanced features.